# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'custom_emoji'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that prints the names of all the members who reacted to a specific message into my console. However, it's giving me an error:

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def whoreacted(self, ctx, message):
        for Member in discord.Reaction.users(message):
            memberlist = Member.name
            print(memberlist)
        await ctx.send('finished!')
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even has the term `custom_emoji`.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are otheruseful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're refering to the classes itself, not to the instances. [Here are the differences](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/#classes-vs-instances).
2. The `message` argument it's going to be a string not a `discord.Message` instance, you should take use of [`MessageConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=messageconv#discord.ext.commands.MessageConverter) to get it.
3. To get the users that reacted to a message you need to use nested loops

Here's your fixed code

```py
@commands.command()
async def whoreacted(self, ctx, message: discord.Message):
    for reaction in message.reactions: # Iterating through every reaction
        async for user in reaction.users(): # Going through every member that reacted with that reaction
            print(user.name)

    await ctx.send('Finished')
```